# Lambda equivalent from Python in PHP

Tags: php, python, multithreading, lambda

I am trying to replicate this code in PHP:

```
pool = ThreadPool(num_parts)
pool.map(
         lambda f: migrate(client, user_id=user_id, files=f), all_files)
```

What is the equivalent structure to use in PHP to iterate over an array while calling a function?
Double bonus points for using it in context of multi-threading on PHP :)

Comment: Just so it's said...if you're asking basic syntax questions, multithreading is probably a ways off yet.  :P

Comment: Gotto upvote @cHao here. Look up PHP's foreach.

Comment: Look up [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: @cHao There is an extension for threads, but I believe it only works in Linux.

Comment: @Havenard: The pthreads extension in PECL supposedly works with any platform that has a pthreads library available (which includes Windows).  But frankly, i'd only recommend it for the lulz.  PHP wasn't made for threading, and most PHP'ers seem to have more than enough trouble anyway with just *one* thread.

Comment: Yeah I guess so. It's already rare to use multithreading at all in any project, let alone in a language that is supposed to be used to generate dynamic web content. Kinda pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, `lambda` creates an anonymous function at run time.

Say:

```
def f(x):
    return x * 2
```

Or:

```
f = lambda x: x * 2
```

Will both create a function `f` that returns `x` times 2, except `lambda` can create an anonymous function, that can be assigned to a variable or passed as argument without  being given a name.

A similar effect can be accomplished in PHP like this:

```
$f = function ($x) { return $x * 2; }
```

Now the variable `$f` is holding a function and can be used as `$f(value)`.

The same way as in Python, you can create this anonymous function directly as an argument without assigning it to a variable or giving it a name. Example:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$arr = array_map(function ($x) { return $x * 2; }, $arr);
// $arr is now [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over a array while calling a function,

```
  $array = array(1,2,3);
  $var = 'foo';

  array_walk($array, function ($value, $key) use ($var) {

       # do something

  });
```